# n number of sql intersections

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Given the following table:

```
MeasureID FilterID
--------- --------
3         1
3         2
4         1
4         2
4         3
4         4
4         5
5         1
```

I want to be able to select filter IDs resulting from the intersection of n number of measures.

```
Example:
MeasureID 3, 4 results in FilterID 1, 2
MeasureID 3, 4, 5 results in FilterID 1
MeasureID 4 results in FilterID 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

A SQL query would be nice and I know this can be done with something along the lines of:

```
select m.FilterID from MeasureFilter m
where m.MeasureID = 3

intersect

select m.FilterID from MeasureFilter m
where m.MeasureID = 4
```

But there is potential for 10s or 100s of measures to be selected.

Ultimately this will be generated in C# using LINQ and the Entity Framework. I know this can be done in some type of a C# loop but it would be nice to come up with some declarative LINQ.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you're using EF, I believe it will generate an `ICollection<Filter> Filters` property on your `Measure` class, so you could just do: `var filters = measures.SelectMany(m => m.Filters).Distinct();`

Comment: In terms of SQL, you want something like `SELECT MeasureID From Table Where FilterID IN (1,2,3,4,5) GROUP BY MeasureID HAVING COUNT(*) == 5` - with the `IN` and `5` tweaked per scenario. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select filterid
from t
where measureid in (3, 4, 5)
group by filterid
having count(*) = 3;
```

The `3` in the `having` clause is the length of the list in the `where`.

Comment: I don't think this will return the desired result. Multiple results may have the same length.

Comment: @andleer . . . That would only happen if there were duplicates in the original data -- there are no duplicates in the sample data and it seems highly unlikely for a junction table.

Comment: This potentially runs over thousands of possible records. And I need the intersection of the grouped sets.  For a measure there will be multiple filters in the mapping table.

Comment: @andleer . . . This is probably the most efficient way to do what you want in SQL.

Comment: Looks like it works. I am going to noodle this for a bit. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Aggregate` with a seed.

For example

```
var measures = new List<MeasureFilter>{
    new MeasureFilter(3,1),
    new MeasureFilter(3,2),
    new MeasureFilter(4,1),
    new MeasureFilter(4,2),
    new MeasureFilter(4,3),
    new MeasureFilter(4,4),
    new MeasureFilter(4,5),
    new MeasureFilter(5,1),
};


// all your MeasureIds that you need
var mIds = new List<int> { 3, 4, 5 };

var res = mIds.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (list, next) =>
{
    if (!list.Any()) //need to initially fill list otherwise no intersection
        return measures
            .Where(m => m.MeasureId == mIds.First())
            .Select(m => m.FilterId)
            .ToList();
    return list
        .Intersect(measures.Where(m => m.MeasureId == next)
        .Select(m => m.FilterId))
        .ToList();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SCKpbt):

```
var filterIDs = context.MeasureFilters.Where(x => measureIds.Contains(x.MeasureID))
    .Select(x => new { x.FilterID, x.MeasureID }).ToList()
    .GroupBy(x => x.MeasureID).Select(x => x.Select(y => y.FilterID))
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is pretty close but the EF didn't like the `Aggregate` function so there needs to be an interim `ToList() after the `GroupBy()`.

Comment: You don't need the `ToList()` after the initial `Select()` and can move it down after the `GroupBy()` That will result in SQL based execution including the group by which should be more efficient and scalable?

Comment: @andleer, `ToList()` after `GroupBy` will be more expensive, because there is not subsequent aggregate operations, such as `Sum()` or `Count()`, so EF still should to return whole set of entities, but also performing additional operations

Answer (score 0):

### Theory

The function you request is a bit like proof by mathematical induction: if you have calculated the result for the first N measureIds, and call it F(N), then the result of the first (N+1) measureIds, is the intersection of F(N) and the 'FilterIds` of element N+1.

In words: once you have calculated your function for `measureIds` 3, 4, 7 (let's say X), then the result for measureIds 3, 4, 7, 10 is the intersection of the 'FilterIds' belonging to 'measureId' 10 with X.

Whenever you see in your requirements something where the output of a calculation is the input for the next calculation together with the next element, the function [Queryable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx) is the function that should immediately pop up in your mind.

### Back to your question

So you need a function with the result of the previous calculations as one parameter and the next element as the other parameter:

- 'previousResult', is a sequence of `FilterIds`. It is the intersection of the 'FilterIds' or all processed `measureIds` until now.
- 'nextMeasureId' is the next `measureId` to process.

The output of the function should be the intersection of the 'previousResult' and all 'FilterIds' belonging to 'measureId'

```
(previousResult, nextMeasureId) =>
    previousResult.Intersect( "all FilterIds belonging to nextMeasureId")
```

Now to formalize this, I need a class.

```
class MeasureResult
{
    public int MeasureId {get; set;}
    public int FilterId {get; set;}
}
```

We create a function with input `IQueryable<MeasureResult>`, which is your original table, other input: `IEnumerable<int>` measureIds.

The output is one sequence of int, which contains the intersection of all `FilterIds` of these `measureIds`: `IEnumerable<int>`

I'll implement it as an extension function, so it can be used as any linq function. See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static IEnumerable<int> IntersectFilterIds(this IQueryable<MeasureResult> measureResults,
    IEnumerable<int> measureIds)
{
    // Todo: check validity input parameters;

    // if no measureIds, return empty sequence:
    if (!measureIds.Any()) return Enumerable.Empty<int>();

    // TODO: add some Aggregate function
}
```

The input of the Aggregate is the sequence of measureIds: take the first and the second measureId and intersect. Take the result and the third measureId and intersect, take the result and the fourth measureId and intersect, etc.

The output of the Aggregate is your requested intersection. This is not the same type as the elements of your input sequence: input elements are integers, output element is a sequence of integers. So you need the Aggregate overload where the result (TAccumulate) is not of the same type as the input sequence elements (TSource). This version needs a `Seed`, which is the outcome of your first intersection: the one with your first element.

We also need a function that takes your table of `measureResults` and one `measureId` and returns all `FilterIds` of this `measureId`. I'll write this as an extension function:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetFilterIds(this IEnumerable<MeasureResult> measureResults,
     int measureId)
{
    return measureResults.Where(measureResult => measureResult.MeasureId == measureId)
        .Select(measureResult.FilterId);
}
```

This function is used to get the intersection result of only the first element (which are all FilterIds of this first element. To be used as the `Seed`. It is also used to get the FilterIds of the next element

Now we have everything to fill the aggregate:

- The seed are the `FilterIds` of the first `measureId`
- The source for the aggregate are all other `measureIds`
- The accumulation function is the intersection of the previousResult and the `FilterIds` of the next `measureId`

  static IEnumerable IntersectFilterIds(this IEnumerable measureResults,
      IEnumerable measureIds)
  {
      if (!measureIds.Any()) return Enumerable.Empty();

  ```
  int firstMeasureId = measureIds.FirstOrDefault();
  IEnumerable<int> seed = measureResults.GetFilterIds(firstMeasureId);
  IEnumerable<int> restOfSequence = measureIds.Skip(1);

  // the aggregate:
  var result = restOfSequence.Aggregate(       // aggregate the rest of the measureIds
      seed,                                    // start with the FilterIds of the first measureId
      (previousResult, nextMeasureId) =>       // the next accumulation is
          previousResult.Intersect(            // the intersection of the previous result
             measureResults.GetFilterId(nextMeasureId) // and all FilterIds of the next measureId
       );
  ```

  }

I'm not sure whether your measureResults and your measureIds are in local memory (IEnumerable) or in tables of a database. If the latter is the case, you can't use functions, so you'll have to write the code instead of the functions, which make it all a bit hard to read, which is why I chose the explanation with functions.

```
IQueryable<MeasureResult> measureResults = ...
IQueryable<int> measureIds = ...

var result = measureIds.Skip(1)        //  = rest of sequence, also: empty if no measureIds
   .Aggregate(

    // first parameter: seed, get FilterIds of first measureId
    // note that seed is empty sequence if there is no first measureId
    measureResults                     
        .Where(measureResult.MeasureId == measureIds.FirstOrDefault())
        .Select(measureResult => measureResult.FilterId),

    // aggregate function: intersection of the previousResult
    // and all FilterIds for the nextMeasureId
    (previousResult, nextMeasureId) => previourResult.Intersect(
        measureResults.Where(measureResult.MeasureId == nextMeasureId)
        .Select(measureResult => measureResult.FilterId));
```